# How can I optimize this C# regex? "^\s?([-*]|\d+[.])\s+"

Tags: c#, regex

I am not an expert at regular expression and have a regular expression

```
^\s?([-*]|\d+[.])\s+
```

I wonder if anyone has ideas about shortening/optimizing/simplifying the above regular expression?

Comment: @Benoit, no I intend to use it in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save *one entire character* (yay!) by writing:

```
^\s?([-*]|\d+\.)\s+
```

Other than that there's not much to do here. If you don't need the contents of the alternation, you could make the group non-capturing and maybe shave a nanosecond or two off by writing

```
^\s?(?:[-*]|\d+\.)\s+
```

but that's very probably the most extreme form of premature optimization you can do. Plus, you need more characters...

Comment: EGADS! +1 for finding the 1-char savings by removing the square brackets; hehe

Answer (score 1):

As Regexes go, that one is pretty darn short and simple as it is. Does it work as you expect? If so, leave it alone.

Comment: oh, ok thanks. I was just wondering if I can somehow simplify that regex so its more readable and easy to understand, whether for me, or someone else looking at it in the future

Comment: Regexes are among some of the least 'readable' constructs you will find in programming, IMO. They just look strange, especially when you are not very fluent with them :P

Comment: +1 Perhaps even the idea of optimizing a regex is little skew?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to optimize it? The contents of your regular expressions are already made of nonredundant atoms. You cannot simplify this more…

Comment: +1 for using the word 'atoms'. I love that word, used appropriately. Don't ask me why! (oh, and for a correct answer!)

Comment: The word “atom” coms from vim documentation on patterns. I did not invent it :)

Comment: Oh yeah, I know; that's what I mean. :) Mostly, I'm way overdue for bed and channeling a Care Bear!